# How can i read the URL from Nativescript WebView?

Tags: angular, nativescript

I want to read the URL of my `WebView` element with the ID `myWebView`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Try reading the url from `loadFinished` event.

Answer (score 0):

you can read url like :

let path:string = document.URL;

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are referencing the WebView in your component

```
  @ViewChild('myWebView') webViewRef: ElementRef;
```

you can add this in the constructor:

```
    this.page.on('navigatedTo', () => {
              let webview: WebView = this.webViewRef.nativeElement;
              let myUrl = webview.src;
    });
```

which should ensure that the native element has been created (you can no trely on Angulars lifecycle hooks for this).